# Pass variable to custom component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have my custom component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-custom-component',
    templateUrl: './my-custom-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-custom-component.css']
})
export class MyCustomComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log('myCustomComponent');
    }
}
```

I can use it like this:

```
<my-custom-component></my-custom-component>
```

But how I can pass a variable? For example:

```
<my-custom-component custom-title="My Title"></my-custom-component>
```

And use this in my component code?

Comment: Using an input in your component: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs

Comment: Just a note: there are 4-5 ways to do so. In this example that's a parent/child relationship, therefore it's easy and `Input` would work. However, for components without relation a service is required, take a look into the blog post https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You need to add `Input` property to your component and then use property binding to pass value to it:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-custom-component',
    templateUrl: './my-custom-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-custom-component.css']
})
export class MyCustomComponent {

    @Input()
    customTitle: string;

    constructor() {
        console.log('myCustomComponent');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.customTitle);
    }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<my-custom-component [customTitle]="yourVariable"></my-custom-component>
```

For more info, check out [this page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html).

Comment: this work! Any idea why `customTitle` variable is undefined in `constructor()` ?

Comment: @rpayanm It's `undefined` because `Input` is Angular's decorator and dit "lives" through Angular's lifecycle, therefore it's only available in `OnInit` and after (`constructor` doesn't have anything to do with Angular, it is initialised before `OnInit`). You can read more about Angular's lifecycle hooks here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: but how can access string "myAnotherVariable" ? <my-custom-component [customTitle]="yourVariable">myAnotherVariable</my-custom-component>

Comment: why potentially customTitle could be "undefined"? because I receive this

Comment: @AnnaLeonenko maybe you specified a static value with `[customTitle]="yourLitteralString"` instead of `customTitle="yourLitteralString"`

Comment: Why "yourVariable" ? Use `{{customTitle}}` in your html code...

Comment: `public customTitle: string`

Comment: I did the same and error is: Property 'customTitle' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor. Can someone help me please!

Answer (score 25):

You can add an `@Input()` decorator to a property on your component.

```
export class MyCustomComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log('myCustomComponent');
    }

    @Input() title: string;
}


<my-custom-component title="My Title"></my-custom-component>
```

or binding title from a variable 'theTitle'

```
<my-custom-component [title]="theTitle"></my-custom-component>
```

See the [`@Input()`decorator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs) documentation.

Comment: BTW, your `@Input` element may need to be declared `public` for it to work properly.