# How to pass to components constructor or ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I have some code I have been working on but I can't find anything on this on google. Basically I want to pass a number that represents an ID to my component to be used when it is instantiated.

I don't know what to try tbh

```
<div class="row">
    <div class = "col-xs-12">
        <app-server *ngFor  = "let server of servers"></app-server>
    </div>
</div>
```

The constructor or ngOnInit will be passed a parameter that is a number.

Comment: Do you mean an `@Input()`?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42287304/1009922).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the **component** of `app-server`, you will need `import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';`

Then we can use `@Input` to let the component know you'll be receiving this variable's value through the template.

So the component will look like

```
//... other imports 
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: "app-server",
    templateUrl: "...,
    styleUrls: ["..."]
})
export class AppServerComponent {

    @Input id: number;

    //.. rest of code

}
```

And in your **template**, you supply the value like so:

```
<app-server *ngFor="let server of servers" [id]="desired_id_value"></app-server>
```

Comment: So we cannot just pass a value? That makes sense but I want to make sure.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky in this case, why would I want to pass the entire server object to itself

Comment: @user3851290 Do you mean whether you can just pass down the entire `server` item? If so, yes you can, you can pass as little or as much as you need. You just need to update the type of @Inpu(). I don't why you would need to pass down one or another, I was just explaining that you can pass as little or as much as you need depending on your requirements and application using @Input() in the child component.

Comment: I am used to C++. Assuming your format what if I wanted to say [id] = servers[server] which I know won't work because "server" is an object so how do I access the index?

Comment: @user3851290 yes, you can pass a value or a constant. ie `<app-server *ngFor="let server of servers" [id]="server.id"></app-server>`